# Xamarin UI Testing: search for elements "marked" with a string ignoring case and searching substring

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently, when I use app.Tap I have to give it the exact string.

I want to do something like `app.Tap("sstring")` and still match elements marked with e.g. "somessting", "someSStRing", etc.

is it possible to have that somehow? it sounds like a simply thing, but I couldn't find a way to do it and it's surprising that there is no option to make it behave that way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it via the function overload and specifying the id?

```
app.Tap(e => e.Id("sstring"));
```

Marked searches many properties on each element to return any matches.

Comment: What if I want to search all: Id, contentDescription and Text?

Comment: You can use the app.Query to get a list of elements back with Marked, then try to choose the correct one. Or you can use .Text instead of Id. But if you want to search all of those properties then you have to expect you will get multiple back and then you will have to choose which one is appropriate.